# Alias for decorator in typescript

Tags: typescript, annotations, decorator, alias

I know there is alias for type:

```js
type ShortTypeName = LooooooooooongTypeName
```

Now I am trying to simplify my complex typescript code with decorator, which I am not very familiar with. Supposed I have following code:

```js
class Foo {
    @SomeDecorator(someConst1, someConst2, someConst3, someConst4)
    property1: string
    @SomeDecorator(someConst1, someConst2, someConst3, someConst4)
    property2: number
    @SomeDecorator(someConst1, someConst2, someConst3, someConst4)
    property3: Date
    @SomeDecorator(someConst1, someConst2, someConst3, someConst4)
    property4: Bar
}
```

I would like to use "alias" so that I can write it like:

```js
alias D = SomeDecorator(someConst1, someConst2, someConst3, someConst4)

class Foo {
    @D
    property1: string
    @D
    property2: number
    @D
    property3: Date
    @D
    property4: Bar
}
```

I know that such alias does not exist, but I guess that this simplification can be done by declaring new decorator (i.e. declaring new function) `D` which calls `SomeDecorator`. How should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I have found the solution. I can define `D` like the following code.

```js
function D(target: any, propertyName: string) {
    const f = SomeDecoration(someConst1, someConst2, someConst3, someConst4)
    f(target, propertyName)
}
```